# How do you apply a .net attribute to a return type

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, return-type

How do I apply the MarshalAsAttribute to the return type of the code below?

```
public ISomething Foo()
{
    return new MyFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx:

```
[return: MarshalAs(<your marshal type>)]
public ISomething Foo()
{
    return new MyFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[return:MarshalAs]
public ISomething Foo()
{
    return new MyFoo();
}
```