# Syntax for applying an attribute to an anonymous method?

Tags: .net, attributes, delegates

This is related to the question about [return type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131456/how-do-you-apply-a-net-attribute-to-a-return-type) and [anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217437/can-i-use-attributes-with-anonymous-classes), but then for anonymous methods (or lambdas), but as far I could find this exact question does not seem to be on stackoverflow yet.

In code for business entities that we generate using CodeSmith we now have `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attributes, so they don't count in code coverage results. Unfortunately, the generated code uses anonymous methods that now still show up in code coverage with names like `Class.<>c__DisplayClass3c` because of the way these are actually handled by the compiler.

Quick code example, with names and types changed to protect the innocent, so to speak:

```
    public delegate T ReturnSomething<T>();

    public static T SafeCall<T>(T whenNotSupported, ReturnSomething<T> method)
    {
        T result;
        try
        {
            result = method();
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            result = whenNotSupported;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void CodeExample()
    {
        string foo = SafeCall<string>("OOPS!", delegate
        {
            //throw new NotSupportedException();
            return "Ok";
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to get `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attributes on these methods so we could get rid of the name-mangled anonymous method names from our generated code from our code coverage results? Or do we need to rewrite that generated code to no longer use anonymous methods?

Putting the `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` on the `method` parameter of the `SafeCall` method definition (before the `ReturnSomething<T>` parameter type) does not compile and maybe would not do exactly what we would like if it would. The following also does not compile:

```
    public static void CodeExample()
    {
        string foo = SafeCall<string>("OOPS!", [DebuggerNonUserCode] delegate
        {
            //throw new NotSupportedException();
            return "Ok";
        });
    }
```

I've tried to have a quick look at the CSharp Language Specification, but have not had any luck finding a syntax that would allow applying attributes to anonymous methods (or lambdas). Did I miss it, or is this (currently?) impossible...?

Comment: Don't think this will get high priority (if it'll ever get done), but I have added the suggestion to MS Connect at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=489925

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot, unfortunately. It is listed on page 401 of the C#3.0 language specification:

> Attributes can be specified at global
>   scope (to specify attributes on the
>   containing assembly or module) and for
>   type-declarations (§9.6),
>   class-member-declarations (§10.1.5),
>   interface-member-declarations (§13.2),
>   struct-member-declarations (§11.2),
>   enum-member-declarations (§14.3),
>   accessor-declarations (§10.7.2),
>   event-accessor-declarations (§10.8.1),
>   and formal-parameter-lists (§10.6.1).

Comment: Thanks, that's the reference I was looking for. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C# does not allow attributes to be applied to anonymous methods.

Are you sure that you really want to apply a `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute to this anonymous method?  The method *is* user code and I would think that you would want to be able to step into it if need be.

Comment: Like I said, the SafeCall method is also called in CodeSmith generated code. There we would like to put a `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` on the anonymous method, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is to exclude the methods from Code Coverage, you can do so by creating a .runsettings file instead of adding an attribute to the method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Starting with C# 10, the custom attributes can be applied to anonymous methods, like so:

```cs
var choose = [DebuggerNonUserCode] object (bool b) => b ? 1 : "two";
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#attributes